# Como posso extrair apenas o PID de um processo?

Tags: shell, shell-script

A minha ideia é a de criar um simples script que possa pesquisar o PID de um processo e matá-lo por exemplo.

Isso é o que fiz até agora mas tem o problema de ao executar o 'ps' não será extraído o PID.

```
echo "nome do processo : "
read $matança
ps -ax | grep $matança
```

Comment: você poderia fazer pipe do resultado do seu grep e utilizar outro grep para pegar somente o PID, algo como: `ps -ax | grep $matança | head -1 | egrep '^\s*[0-9]+'  -o` (`head` é porque seu primeiro grep vai acabar na lista de processos, e você quer apenas o primeiro). Este é só um exemplo para te direcionar, não é nada muito robusto.

Comment: Vê também o comando `killall ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `pgrep`, pro seu caso ficaria assim:

```
pgrep -f $matança
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120304/getting-pids-from-ps-ef-grep-keyword